# getRight, getLeft, getTop returning zero

Tags: android

I am using following code. But all methods are  returning zero value. I know that to get the coordinates of the view our view should be drawn. That why i am using the code in onResume method but still not working. Any Idea?

```
 @Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("Onresume"); 
    System.out.println("tab1 - left" + btn_Tab7 .getLeft());
    System.out.println("tab1 - Top" + btn_Tab7.getTop());
    System.out.println("tab1 - right" + btn_Tab7.getRight());
    System.out.println("tab1 - bottom" + btn_Tab7.getBottom()); 
}
```

Comment: Use a ViewTreeObserver to get notified when the view was drawn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but according to life cycle documentation. All the view already drawn when we entered in OnResume method. Why I need to use ViewTreeObserver class for this purpose. I have already used this class to complete my task but I want to clear my concept instead of just to complete my task.

Answer (score 9):

in `onResume` its too early to call getLeft, getRight ... 
Do it in `onWindowFocusChanged`

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        System.out.println("onWindowFocusChanged"); 
        System.out.println("tab1 - left" + btn_Tab7 .getLeft());
        System.out.println("tab1 - Top" + btn_Tab7.getTop());
        System.out.println("tab1 - right" + btn_Tab7.getRight());
        System.out.println("tab1 - bottom" + btn_Tab7.getBottom());
    }
}
```

Documentation from onResume:

> Keep in mind that **onResume is not the best indicator that your
>   activity is visible to the user**; a system window such as the keyguard
>   may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain
>   that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a
>   game).