# In OnCreate Button.getLeft returns 0

Tags: java, android

In OnCreate Button.getLeft returns 0. Button is created dynamically and Button.performClick() works fine. How get left OnCreate? After OnCreate I can get real left value.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        create_buttons();

        final Button bt = (Button) findViewById(Active);

        bt.performClick();

        msg(bt.getLeft()); //returns 0, why?

    }
```

Comment: Please post `create_buttons();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12053094/804773) you wont be able to retrieve the getLeft() of a View object during the instantiation of your Activity. For the case I linked he talks about `OnResume` but since `OnCreate` occurs prior to `OnResume` [in the lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) you will be seeing similar results.

For a solution take your `msg()` call and drop it to `onWindowFocusChanged`