# Runtime added View does not know it's location

Tags: java, android

I am adding a `View` to a `RelativeLayout` at runtime, which is working fine, but now I would like to display a `TextView` just to left of this `View` but I am unable to retrieve the Top or Left of this `View` in order to calculate the `TextView`'s position.

The code I have is

```
private void displayGuitar() {
    for (GuitarString guitarString: guitar.getGuitarStrings()) {
        GuitarStringView guitarStringView = new GuitarStringView(context, attributeSet, guitarString);
        this.addView(guitarStringView);

        // Add Note name
        TextView noteNameView = new TextView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams noteParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        noteParams.addRule(LEFT_OF, guitarStringView.getId());
        Log.w("string top", String.valueOf(guitarStringView.getTop()));
        Log.w("string left", String.valueOf(guitarStringView.getLeft()));
        noteParams.setMargins(0, 0, 2, 0);
        noteNameView.setLayoutParams(noteParams);           
        noteNameView.setText(guitarString.getTunedNote().getNoteName(0));
        this.addView(noteNameView);
    }
}
```

This results in the TextViews all appearing on top of each other (in the correct X position) but I can't set the Top margin as both of the Log statements return 0. How can I determine what the Top position of the `GuitarStringView` is?

**EDIT**
Following advice from laalto I have now generated ID for the `guitarStringView` and confirmed it's being assigned. However, if I use `LEFT_OF`, `RIGHT_OF` etc the `TextView`s are not displayed, but if I use `ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT` they're displayed fine? Code is now as follows

```
private void displayGuitar() {
    for (GuitarString guitarString: guitar.getGuitarStrings()) {
        GuitarStringView guitarStringView = new GuitarStringView(context, attributeSet, guitarString);
        int viewId = guitarStringView.generateViewId();
        guitarStringView.setId(viewId);
        this.addView(guitarStringView);

        // Add Note name
        TextView noteNameView = new TextView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams noteParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        noteParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, viewId);
        noteNameView.setLayoutParams(noteParams);
        noteNameView.setText(guitarString.getTunedNote().getNoteName(0));
        this.addView(noteNameView);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
The accepted fix didn't work at first as I hadn't override the `onMeasure()` of my `GuitarStringView` which according to the documentation [defaults to 100x100.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#custom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `guitarStringView` doesn't have an id and `getId()` will return `-1`, that is, `NO_ID`. The `LEFT_OF` rule therefore doesn't work as it doesn't refer to any actual id. To fix that, just set some id to the view.

Second, the view has not been measured nor laid out yet so that's why size and position come out as zeros.

---

> using addRule with any of LEFT_OF, RIGHT_OF or BELOW the TextView is no longer displayed at all

Possibly the string view is already taking up all horizontal space. Add another constraint such as `ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT` to make the text view left edge align with parent relative layout's left edge.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it makes sense what you're saying. But at point will they be laid out and measured so that I can get it's position?

Comment: You can get the measures e.g. in an `onGlobalLayout` listener. But that shouldn't be necessary. Instead, just use `RelativeLayout`. In the rare cases where it isn't powerful enough, you should be writing your own custom layout (with overridden measure/layout code) anyway.

Comment: OK, I've set the ID of the `guitarStringView` using `generateViewId()` and checked the IDs generated (which are 1 to 6) however now using `addRule` with any of `LEFT_OF`, `RIGHT_OF` or `BELOW` the TextView is no longer displayed at all?

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck, the `TextViews` just won't appear when I set them relative to the `GuitarStringView`

Comment: This worked once I realised that I needed to override `onMeasure()` on my `GuitarStringView` class

Answer (score 0):

You said "at runtime", which means you're potentially invoking this method in onCreate, or onResume. These methods should start behaving as expected in onWindowFocusChanged(boolean).

See this other question:
[getRight, getLeft, getTop returning zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052570/getright-getleft-gettop-returning-zero)