# Android: Detect left edge of screen minus 100dp

Tags: android, android-screen

I have 3 images that start with a translationX of 300dp, 400dp and 500dp. So only one is visible when the activity starts, and the other 2 are off-screen (right edge). They run in a handler that every 50ms moves them 30dp left. What I need to do is detect when any of the images have reached the left edge of the screen *minus* 100dp, so 100dp off-screen, then set them all the way to the right edge again, *plus* 100dp.

I have been researching for hours and I can't seem to find any way to tell the code where the screen edge is. I've found similar questions, but they all seem to already have the screen edge stored in a variable and are trying to do something with it (without showing how they got that variable).

This is what I've been using, which works for some time, but after a few passes the ki blasts disappear (suddenly only 2 will be showing, then 1, and finally none)...

```
public void kiBlastHandler() {
    kiHandler = new Handler();
    kiHandler.postDelayed(kiRunnable, 50);
}

    private Runnable kiRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (gameRunning) {
                // Ki Blasts
                ImageView kiBlast1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kiBlast1);
                ImageView kiBlast2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kiBlast2);
                ImageView kiBlast3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kiBlast3);

                // Ki blast movement
                kiBlast1.setX(kiBlast1.getX() - currentSpeed);
                kiBlast2.setX(kiBlast2.getX() - currentSpeed);
                kiBlast3.setX(kiBlast3.getX() - currentSpeed);

                // Images for lives
                ImageView imgLives = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLives);
                if (currentLives == 3) {
                    imgLives.setImageResource(R.drawable.lives_03);
                } else if (currentLives == 2) {
                    imgLives.setImageResource(R.drawable.lives_02);
                } else if (currentLives == 1) {
                    imgLives.setImageResource(R.drawable.lives_01);
                }

                // Ready the vibration for losing life
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

                // Handle losing lives
                if (kiBlast1.getTranslationX() == -1100) {
                    currentLives = (currentLives - 1);
                    v.vibrate(vibrateLives);
                    kiBlast1.setTranslationX(600);
                }

                if (kiBlast2.getTranslationX() == -1100) {
                    currentLives = (currentLives - 1);
                    v.vibrate(vibrateLives);
                    kiBlast2.setTranslationX(600);
                }

                if (kiBlast3.getTranslationX() == -1100) {
                    currentLives = (currentLives - 1);
                    v.vibrate(vibrateLives);
                    kiBlast3.setTranslationX(600);
                }
            }

            // No lives left
            if (currentLives == 0) {
                if (gameRunning) {
                    gameRunning = false;
                    gameOver();
                }
            }

            kiHandler.postDelayed(kiRunnable, 50);
        }
    };
```

Can anyone please assist? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Firs you need to convert 100dp into pixel then use this in your run if(imageView.left <= -100){move the images to the right}!

Comment: Hi @MuhammadBabar, thank you for showing me the getLeft() method. But this seems to return 0. I have tried to use...  if (kiBlast1.getTranslationX() <= (viewMain.getLeft() - 100)) {//move right}. The viewMain is my top level RelativeLayout view, which is the full screen. viewMain.getLeft() returns 0. I wanted to say "If the X-position is 100 left of the 0 mark, then move right". But the code turns into "viewMain.left() == 0, therefore move the kiBlast 100 left from wherever it already is". 

Do you know what I have done wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052570/getright-getleft-gettop-returning-zero for why getLeft returns 0.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar .. I think that's a bit different. I tried using Toast to display "Left: " + viewMain.getLeft() + ", Right: " + viewMain.getRight() and it shows me "Left: 0, Right: 1080" which I believe is correct as viewMain is the entire screen size. I think my problem is that the code is not saying "when at x-position of -100 ...." but rather saying "when x-position is -100 of current position". So when the activity starts, the images move 100 left, then immediately move right again.

Comment: You need to do `. if (kiBlast1.getLeft <=  - 100))` then as viewMain.getLeft will always be 0.

Comment: Hi again @MuhammadBabar, I have now fixed it. Actually, using `if (kiBlast1.getLeft <= - 100))` didn't work because the `getLeft()` value of `kiBlast1` changes every 50ms. But it was a simple fix. I was using `getTranslationX()` when I should have used `getX()`. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @MuhammadBabar I was able to work out the problem. I was using:

```
if (kiBlast1.getTranslationX() == -1100) {// etc }
```

When I was supposed to use the `getX()` function:

```
if (kiBlast1.getX() <= (viewMain.getX() - 100)) {// etc }
```

and it's now working perfectly! I hope this helps others to understand how the coordinates of objects works as it had me very confused!